# node js ошибка Rethrow non-MySQL errors

Tags: node.js, express

такой код:

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
let email = req.body.email;
let pass = req.body.pass;
db.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE ?', {email:email} , function (error, results, fields){
    console.log(results);
    if(results[0]===undefined){
        let timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
        db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', {email:email,pass:pass,registered:timestamp,logined:timestamp} , function (error, results, fields){
            req.session.uid = results.insertId;
            res.status(200).send('{"ok":true}');
        });
    }else{
        res.status(200).send('{"ok":false,"msg":"Уже зарегистрирован"}');
    }
  });
});
```

в итоге ошибка:

> throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>           ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>       at Query. (/home/admin/nodejs/routes/user.js:40:13)

пишет что ошибка в этой строчке

```
if(results[0]===undefined){
```

а в чем ошибка не пойму - там же идет проверка на "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#error-handling

Чтобы уловить ошибки, которые вы бросаете, попробуйте следующий фрагмент:

```
con.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("[mysql error]",err);
});
```

Comment: а где этоо прописывать то? сори, новичок в ноде

Comment: после con.connect()

Comment: в представленном коде даже нет connect in Mysql

Comment: т.е вот так:
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var db = mysql.createPool({
 connectionLimit : 10,
 host     : 'localhost',
 user     : 'admin_any',
 password : 'VC6VPIng7O',
 database : 'admin_any'
});
db.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("[mysql error]",err);
});

Answer (score 1):

Сперва-наперво вам нужно проверить аргумент `error`. Не зря же он вам передаётся. Если он есть `if (error) {}`, значит произошла ошибка при запросе. Но вы сразу пытаетесь извлечь первую строку, предполагая, что это массив. Но нет, вам в ошибке пишется, что аргумент `results` на самом деле `undefined`, что говорит как раз об ошибке.

Можно обработать например так `if (error) { return res.status(500).send(error.message) }`

Answer (score 0):

```
    db.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE ?', {email:email} , function (error, results, fields){
```

после этого напиши 
console.log("Твоя ошибка =" + " " + "error")